# How do I parse class hierarchies with gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a class hierarchy that I want to convert to and from GSON. I'm not sure how to approach this with GSON (I currently have a `Factory` class that looks at the JSONObject and based on presence or absence of keys it calls the right constructor, which in turn delegates some of its work to the super class). When I store these objects in the local SQLite DB, I use an integer to denote their type and the factory class uses this type to call the right constructor. I don't have this *type* in the JSON (which isn't mine).

**How do I tell GSON based on the contents of the JSON object which type of object to instantiate for me?**

In the examples below, treat `...` inside the JSON brackets as *there may or may not be more elements*

Here's a breakdown of the class hierarchy:

There is a base abstract type: `SuperType` with a JSON representation `{"ct":12345,"id":"abc123 ...}`

There are 2 main abstract sub types: `TypeA` (has json key *"a"*) and `TypeB` (has json key *"b"*)

**TypeA**

Example: `{"ct":12345,"id":"abc123, "a":{...}}`

`TypeA` has 15 children (Let's call these `TypeA_A` to `TypeA_P`). The JSON representation of these objects would be something like `{"ct":12345,"id":"abc123, "a":{"aa":1 ...} ...}` or `{"ct":12345,"id":"abc123, "a":{"ag":"Yo dawg I head you like JSON" ...} ...}`

**TypeB**

Example: `{"ct":12345,"id":"abc123, "b":{...} ...}`

`TypeB` has another abstract subtype (`TypeB_A`) and few children (Let's call these `TypeB_B` to `TypeB_I`). The JSON representation of these objects would be `{"ct":12345,"id":"abc123, "b":{"ba":{...} ...} ...}` or `{"ct":12345,"id":"abc123, "b":{"bg":"Stayin alive" ...} ...}`

I *could* throw it all in one monster type and treat each of the sub types as an inner object, but I'll end up with a lot of inner members that are null (sort of like a tree with a lot of branches that lead to nowhere). As a result, I'll end up with a lot of `if (something==null)` just to determine which one of these types I'm dealing with.

I've looked at `TypeAdapter` and `TypeAdapterFactory`, but I'm still not sure how to approach this since I have to look at the content of the incoming JSON.

**How do I tell GSON based on the contents of the JSON object which type of object to instantiate for me?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, the RTTAF approach was a push in the right direction, but it expects me to have a field that denotes which subtype I'm using. In my specific case, I have subtypes and subtypes of those subtypes. This is what I ended up doing:

**UPDATE**: [Created Github gist](https://gist.github.com/copolii/8892546)

Note: In my test project (below), I'm using GSON and Lombok for annotations.

**The Type Factory**

```
public class CustomTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create (final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type) {
        if (type.getRawType () != SuperType.class)
            return null;

        final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter (this, type);

        return new TypeAdapter<T> () {
            @Override
            public void write (final JsonWriter jsonWriter, final T t) throws IOException {
                delegate.write (jsonWriter, t);
            }

            @Override
            public T read (final JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException, JsonParseException {
                JsonElement tree = Streams.parse (jsonReader);
                JsonObject object = tree.getAsJsonObject ();

                if (object.has ("a"))
                    return (T) readTypeA (tree, object.getAsJsonObject ("a"));

                if (object.has ("b"))
                    return (T) readTypeB (tree, object.getAsJsonObject ("b"));

                throw new JsonParseException ("Cannot deserialize " + type + ". It is not a valid SuperType JSON.");
            }

            private TypeA readTypeA (final JsonElement tree, final JsonObject a) {
                if (a.has ("aa"))
                    return gson.getDelegateAdapter (CustomTypeAdapterFactory.this, TypeToken.get (TypeA_A.class)).fromJsonTree (tree);

                if (a.has ("ab"))
                    return gson.getDelegateAdapter (CustomTypeAdapterFactory.this, TypeToken.get (TypeA_B.class)).fromJsonTree (tree);

                if (a.has ("ac"))
                    return gson.getDelegateAdapter (CustomTypeAdapterFactory.this, TypeToken.get (TypeA_C.class)).fromJsonTree (tree);

                throw new JsonParseException ("Cannot deserialize " + type + ". It is not a valid TypeA JSON.");
            }

            private TypeB readTypeB (final JsonElement tree, final JsonObject b) {
                if (b.has ("ba"))
                    return gson.getDelegateAdapter (CustomTypeAdapterFactory.this, TypeToken.get (TypeB_A.class)).fromJsonTree (tree);

                if (b.has ("bb"))
                    return gson.getDelegateAdapter (CustomTypeAdapterFactory.this, TypeToken.get (TypeB_B.class)).fromJsonTree (tree);

                if (b.has ("bc"))
                    return gson.getDelegateAdapter (CustomTypeAdapterFactory.this, TypeToken.get (TypeB_C.class)).fromJsonTree (tree);

                throw new JsonParseException ("Cannot deserialize " + type + ". It is not a valid TypeB JSON.");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**SuperType.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class SuperType {
    @SerializedName ("ct")
    protected long creationTime;
    @SerializedName ("id")
    protected String id;
}
```

`Type_A` has no additional data in its level, but does have some common behaviours (methods omitted here for simplicity and because they are irrelevant to parsing).

**TypeA.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode (callSuper = true)
@ToString (callSuper = true)
public class TypeA extends SuperType {}
```

**TypeA_A.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode (callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class TypeA_A
  extends TypeA {

    @SerializedName ("a")
    protected AA aValue;

    @ToString
    private static class AA {
        @SerializedName ("aa")
        private String aaValue;
    }
}
```

Other Type_A children are very similar to TypeA_A.

`Type_B` is slightly more complex as it has its own data *and* behaviours (again, omitted for simplicity):

**TypeB.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode (callSuper = true)
@ToString (callSuper = true)
public class TypeB extends SuperType  {

// no member declared here

    protected static abstract class B {
        @SerializedName ("b1")
        protected String b1Value;
        @SerializedName ("b2")
        protected String b2Value;
    }
}
```

**Type_BA.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode (callSuper = true)
@ToString (callSuper = true)
public class TypeB_A
  extends TypeB {

    @SerializedName ("b")
    protected BA bValue;

    @ToString
    private static class BA extends B {
        @SerializedName ("ba")
        private String baValue;
    }
}
```

**TypeB_B.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode (callSuper = true)
@ToString (callSuper = true)
public class TypeB_B
  extends TypeB {

    @SerializedName ("b")
    protected BB bValue;

    @ToString
    private static class BB extends B {
        @SerializedName ("bb")
        private String bbValue;

        @SerializedName ("bb1")
        private String bb1Value;
    }
}
```

There may be some typos here because I had to change the actual type names and values, but I will create a basic java code example and will post to Github.

Thanks to @Jesse Wilson and @Argyle for their help in pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

There's a standard extension `TypeAdapter` called [RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java) that makes this straightforward.

The [test case](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/test/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactoryTest.java) provides some sample code:

```
RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<BillingInstrument> rta = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(
    BillingInstrument.class)
    .registerSubtype(CreditCard.class);
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(rta)
    .create();

CreditCard original = new CreditCard("Jesse", 234);
assertEquals("{\"type\":\"CreditCard\",\"cvv\":234,\"ownerName\":\"Jesse\"}",
    gson.toJson(original, BillingInstrument.class));
BillingInstrument deserialized = gson.fromJson(
    "{type:'CreditCard',cvv:234,ownerName:'Jesse'}", BillingInstrument.class);
assertEquals("Jesse", deserialized.ownerName);
assertTrue(deserialized instanceof CreditCard);
```

Comment: I've successfully used this thing too.  It's fairly easy to add a default handler to it as a catch-all for any unrecognized subclasses too, though you should be careful with that.

Comment: @Jesse Thanks. I did come across the RTTAF, but I'm still not sure how to determine *which* class ... or does GSON automatically search the `@SerializedName` fields to match it up? I guess what I'm really asking is do I have to manually peek into the json and give GSON hints or does it automatically figure it out based on the registered subtypes? Also, do I have to register the abstract types or just the concrete ones? I think only registering the concrete classes should do, but it doesn't hurt to ask :)

Comment: @copolii By default, it looks for a `String` field called `type` to use as a map lookup, but I believe you can specify a different field if you wish.

Comment: @Argyle yeah, thanks, noticed that in the code a bit ago. Gonna write up a little example and test it out. It's easier to adapt it for my use if I can see *how* it's broken