# Kotlin Gson with Data Classes

Tags: json, kotlin, gson, data-class

Trying to parse a complex json object using Gson. Here are the data classes that are failing:

```
data class Advisor(
    val students: List<Student>?,
)

sealed class Student {
    data class BusinessMajor(val name: String, val items: List<Courses>) : Student()
    data class ArtsMajor(val name: String, val items: List<Courses>) : Student()
}
```

At runtime, I get this exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke private
>   com.mysite.myapp.ApiResponse$Student() with no args

I've read that this can be created by trying to parse abstract classes, but all the posts I've read are for Java. I don't see anything that helps with Kotlin data classes, particularly wrapped with a `sealed` class.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please show the code that fails.

Comment: So, what is the correct model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sealed types classes cannot be instantiated : [see here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html)

> A sealed class is abstract by itself, it cannot be instantiated directly and can have abstract members.
>
> Sealed classes are not allowed to have non-private constructors (their constructors are private by default).

Answer (score 1):

It should work the same as in Java. Adapting the example from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21641225/9204:

```
val rta = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(Student::class.java)
    .registerSubtype(Student.BusinessMajor::class.java)
    .registerSubtype(Student.ArtsMajor::class.java)
val gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(rta)
    .create()
```

But:

1. This way you need to write a factory for every sealed class. Maybe there is a helper library to avoid this problem, but if so I haven't found it.
2. See also [Why Kotlin data classes can have nulls in non-nullable fields with Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52837665/why-kotlin-data-classes-can-have-nulls-in-non-nullable-fields-with-gson)

On the whole, I'd strongly consider using Moshi or another Kotlin-aware JSON library.